# Azure SQL and DTUs

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage

A newb question. I don't understand the DTU concept that is attached to the Azure SQL database.

Is DTU more like petrol tank on a car where you have certain amount and if you use it you have to fill up or is it more like your car's RPM where you need to keep it under a threshold? I hope that make sense.

For example if each user uses **1 DTU/Second**, and I have **10 DTUs available** then which one of the following two is correct:

1. Five users can use the site for hours/days/months...because it will
   always be 5 DTUs/Second
2. Five users can only use the site for 2 seconds...because it adds up
   to 10 DTUs in that 2 seconds and depletes my reserve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It most likely as the first concept of your question.

The amount of resources is calculated as a number of Database Transaction Units or DTUs and is a bundled measure of compute, storage, and IO resources.

We can understand DTU is the performance unit of the database.

More information about DTU, we can refer to: 
[Database Transaction Units (DTUs) and elastic Database Transaction Units (eDTUs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-what-is-a-dtu)

Comment: Thanks Lee. I think you are right.In there it keeps referring to rates, and performance. So I guess that is not too bad, if it was other than that it would get too expensive to use for small projects. Thanks again.